# Como permitir caracteres especiales en sp_xml_preparedocument

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy tratando de ejecutar esto en sql server 2014 y cuando ejecuto me genera el siguiente error:

Msg 6602, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0] The error description is 'A semi colon character was expected.'.

Se que es por el caracter & que esta dentro de la etiqueta  ACTIVITYTYPENAME contiene el caracter &, cuando se lo quito se ejecuta perfecto.

```
DECLARE @@hDoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @@hDoc OUTPUT,
'<ROOT>
<mdscheduler REASON="Client Not Home" ACTIVITY="" ACTIVITYTYPENAME="sdf &bsf sf" ACTIVITYTYPECODE="SD1233" ALLDAY="F" BACKCOLOR="0" CONTACT="Anthony Adams" DONE="F" FONTCOLOR="-16777208" FONTSIZE="8" ICONINDEX="-1" NOTES="DAY PHONE   : 
NIGHT PHONE : 
CELL PHONE  : 
CO-PAY     : $ 0.00
ALERT      : 
Facility : WAIV
" ACTIVITYID="419275610553243" DUEDATE="" FACILITYCODE="WAIV" REMINDER="F" REMINDERTIME= "" SUBJECT="Anthony Adams - CANCELLED" THERAPISTCODE = "AMBHUN" PATIENTCODE="1800244" TIMEIN="8:15 AM" TIMEOUT="8:30 AM" GROUPCREATIONID="437275110343288" ENDDATE="09/19/2019" TRANSDATE="09/19/2019" STATUS="reoccurrence" />

</ROOT>'
INSERT MdScheduler
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@@hDoc, '/ROOT/mdscheduler')
WITH mdscheduler
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @@hDoc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es con el carácter *`&`*  de  `... ACTIVITYTYPENAME="sdf &bsf sf" ...`, necesitarás "escaparlo", es decir reemplazarlo por `&amp;`. Por ejemplo, mediante un `REPLACE()`:

```
DECLARE @@hDoc int
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000);

SET @doc ='<ROOT>
<mdscheduler REASON="Client Not Home" ACTIVITY="" ACTIVITYTYPENAME="sdf &bsf sf" ACTIVITYTYPECODE="SD1233" ALLDAY="F" BACKCOLOR="0" CONTACT="Anthony Adams" DONE="F" FONTCOLOR="-16777208" FONTSIZE="8" ICONINDEX="-1" NOTES="DAY PHONE   : 
NIGHT PHONE : 
CELL PHONE  : 
CO-PAY     : $ 0.00
ALERT      : 
Facility : WAIV
" ACTIVITYID="419275610553243" DUEDATE="" FACILITYCODE="WAIV" REMINDER="F" REMINDERTIME= "" SUBJECT="Anthony Adams - CANCELLED" THERAPISTCODE = "AMBHUN" PATIENTCODE="1800244" TIMEIN="8:15 AM" TIMEOUT="8:30 AM" GROUPCREATIONID="437275110343288" ENDDATE="09/19/2019" TRANSDATE="09/19/2019" STATUS="reoccurrence" />
</ROOT>'

SET @doc = replace(@doc, '&', '&amp;')
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @@hDoc OUTPUT, @doc
```

Y por cierto, eventualmente deberías reemplazar cualquiera de los caracteres "prohibidos" de XML:

```
" ->  &quot;
' ->  &apos;
< ->  &lt;
> ->  &gt;
& ->  &amp;
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio fue de muchísima ayuda su respuesta